# How to show Laplacian of Poisson kernel is zero?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Define the Poisson's kernel:
$$K(x,y):=\frac{2x_n}{n\alpha(n)}\frac{1}{|x-y|^n}$$
where $x\in \mathbb{R}^n_{+}, y\in \partial \mathbb{R}^n_{+}$

> How to show $\Delta_x K(x,y)=0$?

I feel that 
$$|x-y|^{-n}=(|y|^2+x_n^2)^{-n/2}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity you've written down ('I feel that..') holds at the boundary -- i.e. for $x\in \partial\mathbb{R}^n_+$. In general you will have to admit interior points for $x$.

If you really define the expression for $K$ only for $y\in \partial \mathbb{R}^n_+$, then, as a matter of fact, $y = (0, \dots, y_n)$.

Apart from all that, the answer to your question is 'By calculation' (it's not that hard, assuming ($n\ge 3$) and you got the expression right.).